# Understanding sendmail config

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, sendmail

I am trying to get php to send mail via the "mail() command, on a Ubuntu linux box. The mail appears to be going and then getting dropped by send mail - and I am at a loss as to what to do about it.

The php mail() function returns true. The mail is not delivered. I have set up evolutoin to deliver vi SMTP on localhost, and sent an email to the same user - and it is delivered.

The /var/log/mail.log file contains the following entries.

```
Jul  9 15:15:34 anake postfix/pickup[1292]: 02879340040: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Jul  9 15:15:34 anake postfix/cleanup[2079]: 02879340040: message-id=<20110709141534.02879340040@anake>
Jul  9 15:15:34 anake postfix/qmgr[1293]: 02879340040: from=<www-data@anake.ianhobXXson.co.uk>, size=411, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  9 15:15:36 anake postfix/smtp[2082]: 02879340040: to=<hobXXson42@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.ntlworld.com[81.103.221.11]:25, delay=2.3, delays=0.1/0.02/2.1/0.13, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host smtp.ntlworld.com[81.103.221.11] $
Jul  9 15:15:36 anake postfix/cleanup[2079]: 5370B340042: message-id=<20110709141536.5370B340042@anake>
Jul  9 15:15:36 anake postfix/bounce[2083]: 02879340040: sender non-delivery notification: 5370B340042
Jul  9 15:15:36 anake postfix/qmgr[1293]: 5370B340042: from=<>, size=2228, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  9 15:15:36 anake postfix/qmgr[1293]: 02879340040: removed
Jul  9 15:15:36 anake postfix/local[2084]: 5370B340042: to=<www-data@anake.ianhobXXson.co.uk>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0/0.02/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jul  9 15:15:36 anake postfix/qmgr[1293]: 5370B340042: removed
```

I do not understadn where it gets the "from" address from. The actual code executed is this:-

```
<?php 
    $to      = 'hobXXson42@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Test email';  
    $message = 'hello - this has gone round the loop';
    $headers = 'From: ian@ianhobXXson.co.uk' . "\n" .
              'Reply-To: ian@ianhobXXson.co.uk' . "\n" .
              'X-Mailer: PHP/'. phpversion()."\r\n";
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo "Message sent OK";
    } else {
        echo "message send failed";
    }
```

?>

Can anyone spot what is going wrong, and what I can do about it? Email addresses slightly munged in a rather obvious way. 
Ian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "from" here is the envelope sender, i.e., the address which will end up in the Return-Path header. This header cannot be changed in the same way as other headers since this is not actually part of the mail but part of the envelope. Return-Path is the address which bounces is sent to, among other things.

You may be able to change the envelope sender by using the fifth argument of the `mail()` function. Postfix (which your server is running), Sendmail and Exim all makes it possible to change the envelope sender using the `-f` flag:

```
...
$extra_parameters = '-fian@ianhobXXson.co.uk';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $extra_parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks Emil - that worked a charm. I actually ended up setting the sendmail_path line in php.ini to "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -r ian@ianhobXXson.co.uk" (which does the same thing). Thanks again.